# Postfix won't reject undeliverable messages

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

I'm not shure about the wording. Maybe bouncing is the right word.

Problem is, that a local user did send a message to a non-existing domain. Now I expected that postfix will send the message back to the sender. Isn't this default behavior? And if not, what have I to do to get this working?

If someone's interesseted in my postfix configuration: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2AF2EpGL) (because it's to large to post here).

The problem in simple steps:

1. james.bond@mydomain.org sends a message via mail.mydomain.org to alfred@nonexistenddomain.org
2. Mail stays in postfix' mailqueue now for over 5 days.

My intention:

- Notify the sender (james.bond@mydomain.org) that message couldn't get delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix is saving the message to try again later. [You can use these parameters to change this behavior.](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#hammer)

Be careful because remote servers using Greylisting may not accept messages if you haven't tried enough times or waited long enough.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set a positive time value for [`delay_warning_time`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#delay_warning_time).

e.g.: `delay_warning_time = 90m`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you want to look at is `bounce_queue_lifetime`.

It seems that in your configuration it's set to 2 days, which is kind of low. Perhaps you changed it *after* this issue occurred? Or did you remember to reload Postfix after changing it?

Comment: I set this down before posting this question but it doesn't affekt the messages in the queue. Two days later the problem where solved.